# Burn through old gas or mix it?

Tags: fuel-system, gasoline, fuel-injection

Vehicle has been sitting unused for 3 months with a half tank of gasoline.

Is it better to burn through that half tank of fuel, or mix it with a fresh half tank and burn through that mixture?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot siphon/extract the old fuel, it is better to dilute the old fuel with fresh fuel to reduce the likelihood of clogging up the fuel filter when you fire it up for the first time.

Comment: At only 3 months old, I'd dilute and burn through as well.